# Minimum of sum of absolute values

Tags: algorithm, math, sum

Problem statement:

There are 3 arrays A,B,C all filled with positive integers, and all the three arrays are of the same size.

Find min(|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-a|) where a is in A, b is in B, c is in C.

---

I worked on the problem the whole weekend. A friend told me that it can be done in linear time. I don't see how that could be possible.

How would you do it ?

Comment: Not an answer but a hint; dynamic programming.  Think about extending an existing solution by one element of C.  The solution to the new slightly bigger problem is either the old solution or the old solution updated somehow.

Comment: wouldn't dynamic programming yield a O(n^3) solution ? what kind of recurrence would I have ? recurrence with what arguments ?

Comment: I'm wondering... even in the case where you have just two arrays, I can't see how to be sure that you need to sort the arrays and that there is no linear solution...

Comment: then O(nlogn) ... anything consistently better than the obvious O(n^3) would be interesting to understand the mechanics of

Comment: Why is this tagged `code-golf`?

Comment: Interestingly, whether the "closest pair" problem can be solved in linear time depends on your model of computation.  See the intro to [this paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/grant/cp.pdf) for details.  It might be possible to adapt their ideas to answer this question in linear time as well.  Hm...

Comment: Well if the representations of your numbers are bounded, then you can use a bucket sort to do this in linear time :D

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, because the OP doesn't know what it means and hasn't read the SO guidelines for the code-golf tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I think I can do it in O(n log n).  I can only do O(n) if the arrays are initially sorted.

First, observe that you can permute `a`,`b`,`c` however you like without changing the value of the expression.  So let `x` be the smallest of `a`,`b`,`c`; let `y` be the middle of the three; and let `z` be the maximum.  Then note that the expression just equals `2*(z-x)`.  (Edit: This is easy to see... Once you have the three numbers in order, `x < y < z`, the sum is just `(y-x) + (z-y) + (z-x)` which equals `2*(z-x)`)

Thus, all we are really trying to do is find three numbers such that the outer two are as close together as possible, with the other number "sandwiched" between them.

So start by sorting all three arrays in O(n log n).  Maintain an index into each array; call these `i`, `j`, and `k`.  Initialize all three to zero.  Whichever index points to the smallest value, increment that index.  That is, if `A[i]` is smaller than `B[j]` and `C[k]`, increment `i`; if `B[j]` is smallest, increment `j`; if `C[k]` is smallest, increment k.  Repeat, keeping track of `|A[i]-B[j]| + |B[j]-C[k]| + |C[k]-A[i]|` the whole time.  The smallest value you observe during this march is your answer.  (When the smallest of the three is at the end of its array, stop because you are done.)

At each step, you add one to exactly one index; but you can only do this `n` times for each array before hitting the end.  So this is at most `3*n` steps, which is O(n), which is less than O(n log n), meaning the total time is O(n log n).  (Or just O(n) if you can assume the arrays are sorted.)

Sketch of a proof that this works:  Suppose `A[I]`, `B[J]`, `C[K]` are the `a`, `b`, `c` that form the actual answer; i.e., they have the minimum `|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-a|`.  Suppose further that `a` > `b` > `c`; the proof for the other cases is symmetric.

Lemma: During our march, we do not increment `j` past `J` until after we increment `k` past `K`.  Proof: We always increment the index of the smallest element, and when `k <= K`, `B[J] > C[k]`.  So when `j=J` and `k <= K`, `B[j]` is not the smallest element, so we do not increment `j`.

Now suppose we increment `k` past `K` before `i` reaches `I`.  What do things look like just before we perform that increment?  Well, `C[k]` is the smallest of the three at that moment, because we are about to increment `k`.  `A[i]` is less than or equal to `A[I]`, because `i < I` and `A` is sorted.  Finally, `j <= J` because `k <= K` (by our Lemma), so `B[j]` is also less than `A[I]`.  Taken together, this means our sum-of-abs-diff at this moment is *less* than `2*(c-a)`, which is a contradiction.

Thus, we do not increment `k` past `K` until `i` reaches `I`.  Therefore, at some point during our march `i=I` and `k=K`.  By our Lemma, at this point `j` is less than or equal to `J`.  So at this point, either `B[j]` is less than the other two and `j` will get incremented; or `B[j]` is between the other two and our sum is just `2*(A[i]-C[k])`, which is the right answer.

This proof is sloppy; in particular, it fails to explicitly account for the case where one or more of `a`,`b`,`c` are equal.  But I think that detail can be worked out pretty easily.

Comment: Ok, so your sorting is O(n log n). But the iteratations you describe, what is the complexity of those ?      ;  I have a solution that's O(nlogn + logn + n) also through sorting, then closest pair algorithm for 1D(described here www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf ) , to find the I,J you are refering too above. and then I just iterate through C to find the K.

Comment: also, I don't understand why |a-b| + |b-c| + |c-a| becaomes 2(z-x)

Comment: @jojo: Can you prove that one of the `a,b`, `b,c`, and `c,a` need to be the closest pair from that pair of arrays?  I am not sure that is true, but I also do not have a counterexample...

Comment: @jojo: Found my counter-example.  Consider `A=[0,10,201]` `B=[1,12,100]` `C=[14,101,200]`.  Closest pairs are `0,1` from `A,B`, `100,101` from `B,C`, and `200,201` from `C,A`.  But the right answer is a=10, b=12, c=14.  So you cannot use "closest pair" to solve this problem; you must look at all three arrays at once.

Comment: @Nemo, interesting proof although I'm not sure you proved O(n log n). Very good noticing the sum is essentially 2*(max-min). Personally, I'd stop there and try to minimize that across the three arrays using this knowledge.

Comment: @eternalmatt:  Could you elaborate?  Sorting the arrays is obviously O(n log n).  At each iteration (which is O(1)), exactly one of the `i`, `j`, or `k` gets incremented, and each of those can only get incremented `n` times before hitting the end of the array...  So the "march" is exactly 3*n iterations which is O(n) which is less than O(n log n).  What is your concern?

Comment: @Nemo, well looking more closely at this, I think I can see the logic.  I'm by no means an expert at proofs...some pseudocode to follow this up could go a long way for me.

Comment: @Nemo, Could you elaborate the proof a bit. How does proving the lemma help us? You are also using "proof by contradiction" but what are you assuming to be false at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

I would write a really simple program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, random
A = random.sample(range(100), 10)
B = random.sample(range(100), 10)
C = random.sample(range(100), 10)
minsum = sys.maxint
for a in A:
 for b in B:
  for c in C:
   print 'checking with a=%d b=%d c=%d' % (a, b, c)
   abcsum = abs(a - b) + abs(b - c) + abs(c - a)
   if abcsum < minsum:
    print 'found new low sum %d with a=%d b=%d c=%d' % (abcsum, a, b, c)
    minsum = abcsum
```

And test it over and over until I saw some pattern emerge. The pattern I found here is what would be expected: the numbers that are closest together in each set, regardless of whether the numbers are "high" or "low", are those that produce the smallest minimum sum. So it becomes a nearest-number problem. For whatever that's worth, probably not much.

Comment: this is O(n^3). I use this to generate myself testcases. I was looking for something linear. thanks

Comment: understood. the purpose of a nonoptimal solution is to look for patterns that can then be used to determine a better algorithm.

Comment: I've got a O(n^3) solution written in about five lines of Haskell.