# Minimize max - min after picking 1 element each from N arrays

Tags: algorithm

Given `n` sorted arrays, create a new array by picking one number from each array such that the difference between the max and min of numbers in the new array is minimized.

Example with `n=3` input arrays:

```
A = {4, 10, 15}
B = {1, 13, 29}
C = {5, 14, 28}
```

In this case, the answer would be to pick `15` from array A, `13` from array B, and `14` from array C because `max[{15, 13, 14}] - min[{15, 13, 14}] = 15 - 13 = 2` and there is no other combination that will get a max-min difference lower than 2.

What is the most efficient algorithm?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `max - min = 15 - 13 = 2`?

Comment: Are the arrays always sorted?

Comment: Very closely related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567368/

Comment: I clarified the question, and following this I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: @hexist, Yes, the arrays are always sorted. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let, A1, A2, ... An be n arrays.
 Assuming all the arrays are sorted, if not we can sort them individually.

```
S = [ A1[0], A2[0],...An[0] ]
minSpread = max{S} - min{S}
Iterate i = 1 to L (where L is length of shortest array)
   Remove min{S} from S.
   Insert Ak[i] in S. (where Ak is the kth array from which a value was removed in previous step.)
   minSpread = min(minSpread, max{S} - min{S});
```

As we have to minimize the spread (max-min) only option we have is to squeeze the min 'up' by removing the current min.

Works out in O(N) + O(N*L*logN), where N is no. of arrays and L is lenght of shortest array.

This is a common problem while displaying search results. when we have to show the smallest possible window of the excerpt from the page which contains all the given search words.
Here, A1[] A2[]... An[] contains the indexes of the appearance of words say-W1, W2... Wn.

**Edit:**

Nemo: You're right. The proof is a bit involving. The link provided by you attempts a similar soution. All I can add is:

Considering the facts: 
1. We have to maintain exactly one element from each array. 
2. The arrays are all sorted in increasing order.
Help us in discarding many combinations right away thus, making it possible to do it in a better time as compared to generating all combinations.
for more details visit the link provided by 'Nemo'.

and, complexity can be brought down to O(N) + O(N*L*logN) by maintaining a minheap as suggested. 
where, N is no. of arrays and L is Length of shortest array.

Comment: ???  To minimize max-min, you can also "squeeze the max 'down'".  Also I have no idea what "the kth array from which a value was removed in the previous step" means.  Could you expand on this with some pseudocode?

Comment: Yes, but I am assuming arrays are already sorted. so starting from 0th index of all arrays there will be no space for 'squeezing the max 'down''. Kth array is the one whose value was found to be minimum in resulting set S. and, to fill in that void we bring in the next value as we have to maintain exactly one element from each array.

Comment: OK, I believe this works, since it is essentially the same algorithm as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567368/.  But it is not at all obvious that it has to work.  You do not check all possible combinations, so how are you sure you do not miss the absolute minimum as you march along these arrays?  The proof is not all that simple IMO.  But +1 anyway.  (Also, you should use something other than "N" for the length of the shortest array, since the question already defined N as the number of arrays.  Your algo is actually O(N*L), or O(N*L log L) if the arrays are not initially sorted)

Comment: @Nemo, if we take the cost of computing the min at every step, the complexity will be N*L*N. The main loop can run up to N*L times. At each step, we calculate the min. Calculating the min of N items can take up to O(N) time. Maybe, if we use a min-heap, the min operation will be O(lgN). So, complexity will be N*L*lgN

Comment: @user674669 Heap construction can be done in O(N) and subsequently we can run the main loop for a length of L taking logN steps each to update the min. Hence, O(N) + O(L*logN).

Comment: @srbh.kmr, you have calculated the best case complexity. In the worst case, N*L elements will be inserted into and removed from the heap. Each insertion and removal from the heap takes lgN time. So, total time will be N*L*lgN

Comment: Worst-case example with 3 arrays.

A: 1 4 7, B: 2 5 8, C: 3 6 9

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by recursive backtracking approach:

```
Best = OO
ChoiceArr = [ ]

function rec(i)
       if (i == numArrays)
          calc()
       else
           for j = 0 to Arrays[i].length - 1
               ChoiceArr[i] = Arrays[i][j]
               rec(i + 1)

function calc()
     mn = OO
     mx = -OO
     for i = 0 to ChoiceArr.length - 1
          mn = min(mn, ChoiceArr[i])
          mx = max(mx, ChoiceArr[i])

     Best = min(Best, mx - mn)
```

The complexity is **exponential: O(m ^ n)**, where *m* is the maximum sub-array size, and *n* is the total number of subarrays. This could grow up very fast and consume a lot of time as *n* grows.

Comment: But that's no fun at all. How to do it efficiently?

Comment: @lVlad I cannot find a dynamic programming optimization. I am trying to find hardly.

Comment: @Alexander as opposed to what, a surreal one? That is real, and much better than using magic letters with no inherent meaning actually. Edit: virtual -1 for your edit, it was better before.

Comment: @IVlad, who's talking about magic letters? I can't make any sense of your comment

Comment: @Alexander my point is that "O(m ^ n), where m is the maximum sub-array size, and n is the total number of subarrays" is worse and needlessly more verbose than what it was before, or just `O(arraysSize ^ numArrays)`.

Comment: @lVlad It was wrong, however. The problem-statement has not assumed that all sub-arrays are of the same size. So it is wrong to write `Arrays[0].length`

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy all elements from all arrays into a new array where the elements contain the value from the original array and a unique identifier for the original array. O(n)
2. Sort the new array by value O(n log n)
3. Iterate over the new array - find the sequence that has the minimal difference between its first and last member and also contains members from all original arrays. O(n^2)

C# implementation

```
var arr1 = new[] { 4, 10, 15 };
var arr2 = new[] { 1, 13, 29 };
var arr3 = new[] { 5, 14, 28 };

var sortedAndIndexed = arr1
    .Select(x => new { value = x, array = 'a' })
    .Concat(arr2.Select(x => new { value = x, array = 'b' }))
    .Concat(arr3.Select(x => new { value = x, array = 'c' }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.value)
    .ToList();

var numberOfArrays = 3;
var minValue = sortedAndIndexed.Last().value - sortedAndIndexed.First().value;
var bestSlice = new[] { 0, sortedAndIndexed.Count - 1 };
for (int i = 0; i < sortedAndIndexed.Count; i++)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<char>();
    var firstItem = sortedAndIndexed[i];
    seen.Add(firstItem.array);
    int j = i + 1;
    for (; j < sortedAndIndexed.Count && 
           seen.Count < numberOfArrays && 
           sortedAndIndexed[j].value - firstItem.value < minValue; j++)
    {
        seen.Add(sortedAndIndexed[j].array);
    }
    if (seen.Count == numberOfArrays)
    {
        j -= 1;
        int value = sortedAndIndexed[j].value - firstItem.value;
        if (value < minValue)
        {
            minValue = value;
            bestSlice = new[] { i, j };
        }
    }
}

var arraySeen = new HashSet<char>();
var sliceElements = new List<int>();
for (int i = bestSlice[0]; i <= bestSlice[1]; i++)
{
    var item = sortedAndIndexed[i];
    if (arraySeen.Add(item.array))
    {
        sliceElements.Add(item.value);
    }
}
var elements = sliceElements
      .Select(x => x.ToString())
      .ToArray();
var result = String.Join(", ", elements);
Console.WriteLine("Best slice: "+ result);
```

output:

```
Best slice: 13, 14, 15
```